# IntelliJ: How to create Android widget project?

Tags: android-widget, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, I just uncheck "Create activity" and I get widget-ready project.

In IntelliJ, I tried unchecking "Create Hello World project", but then I cannot compile the app (there isn't Run As Android App option).

At the moment I create a regular Android project and then delete the stuff I do not need. Any faster/automated way?

Thanks

Comment: No one knows the way? Then please tell me how do YOU create a new widget project in IntelliJ! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have created your project, click the down arrow next to the run button on the toolbar and select "Edit Configurations".

In the top left of this window press the plus button and select "Android Application". Finally, name your configuration at the top of the window and change the radio button selection from "Launch Default Activity" to "Do Not Launch Activity".

Comment: THANKS MAN! I would give you 10 pluses, if only I could. You're a savior.

Comment: Since you seem like an expert for Android and IntelliJ, did you possible face the situation that you had to change Android external library in the project (lets say from 2.1 to 2.1 Google API)? I got an error which cannot be solved and it's described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448866/if-i-change-an-external-library-androidmanifest-cannot-parse-file. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As no one answered, I suppose that the only way to create a Widget or Live wallpaper project is to create a regular Android project and then delete the code you don't need from Manifest and Class files.

Looking forward for better solution in IntelliJ.