# If I change an external library: AndroidManifest, cannot parse file

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-manifest, xml-parsing

I open an older project which has a normal Android 2.2 external library registered. I want to use Google maps and I change the external library to Android 2.2 Google APIs. After that I cannot parse the manifest file and I get an error:

```
AnroidManifest.xml
Error: Cannot parse file
```

The error is on the 2nd line in the URI

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

If I hover the error, I get the message: `URI is not registered`.

What's even more weird, when I return an old lilbrary to the project (a normal 2.2), I still have the same error.

What could be the reason for this?

PS. The IDE I use is IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Why not just create a new project and use Google API from the beginning?

Comment: I could, but many times I need to implement Google Maps into older projects. This is such case.

Comment: It seems that this is up to IntelliJ IDEA. Every time I change an external library, I get this message. I tried to exclude this error, and now IntelliJ complains that there is not declaration in the Manifest tag. I say this is a major bug!

Comment: well just a suggestion use Eclipse IDE instead :)

Comment: Well I moved from Eclipse to IntelliJ so there's no point to return back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunatelly, I couldn't find the solution to this issue and, so far, the only way to solve is to create a new project with correct external libraries and to copy files into it.

Comment: Maybe you had this issue? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5624620/cannot-find-package-value-in-androidmanifest-xml-for-module

Comment: It's not my issue (unfortunatelly). I do not have problem neither with the `package` nor nor with manifest location. My problem is in `xmlns:android` just like I said on the first place.

Comment: AddOn: I even tried to disregard this error (alt+enter and then clicked on the suggested option), and now I do not have an error with `xmlns:android`, but rather a new error saying: "Error: Cannot parse file" and the `Manifest` tag is underlined in red.

Answer (score 8):

Try [IDEA 10.5 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+10.5+EAP), it has improved Android support and [easier SDK configuration](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2011/03/new-concept-of-android-sdk-in-intellij-idea-105/). **File | Invalidate** caches may also help.

Comment: Unfortunatelly it did not help

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you only have lower caps characters in the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

In IDEA 12 at least, Preferences > Schemas and DTDs, press the + to add External Schemas and DTDs, in the URI edit field add "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android", press OK to save. This was a little flaky, I had to do it twice, but it worked, the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe check the configuration of your modules. Be sure to mark the relevant folders as "Sources", "Test Sources" or "Excluded".

I had a namespace warning in `res/anim/fade_in.xml`. When I marked the resource folder of my project as "Sources" as shown in the screenshot the namespace errors disappeared.

[image: IntelliJ Modules Settings]