# Cannot find package value in AndroidManifest.xml for module

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When compiling an Android module with Intelij-IDEA I get the following error message:

```
Cannot find package value in AndroidManifest.xml for module
```

The hover help tell me to fill in the Resources page on settings dialogue. But, what actually do I have to fill in?

The Manifest file is pretty sort (it's a library)

```
<manifest
  android:versionCode='1'
  android:versionName='0.1'
  package='com.XXX.datamodel'
  xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'
>
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion='4'
    android:targetSdkVersion='8'
  ></uses-sdk>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please share your manifest file?

Comment: Do you have the correct AndroidManifest.xml path specified in the IDEA Android Facet settings?

Comment: @CrazyCoder: Funny as you say, the path has been horribly mangled up (parts have been repeated inside) and fixing the mess gut things working again.

Make your comment an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such error may occur when the path to the `AndroidManifest.xml` file in the [IDEA Android Facet settings](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/android-facet-page.html) is configured incorrectly. Correcting the **Manifest path** should fix the problem.

Comment: That was it. It seem that IDEA wants to store the path relative and might mess the path up when symbolic links are involved. And that is what I did: I have a symbolic link `/Work` which points to my real development directory. IDEA used `realpath` to first get the path to which the symbolic link points to and then calculated a  relative from the project path to the result. The result is horrible ugly (lots of `../../..`), not very portable and can get messed up very easily. I consider that a design bug.

Answer (score 3):

I got this error message once in a multi-module project where the outer project wasn't an android module, but an inner project was.  Idea recognized the outer project as an android facet and was wrongly configured as such.

I just removed the facet on the outer project by going into Project Structure, selecting the outer module and right clicking on the android facet and deleted it.