# Intellij Android project schema URI not registered?

Tags: android, schema, intellij-idea, uri

I'm using intellij CE 10.5 for my android projects and ran into a weird error.
My project can be built by Eclipse and Ant, and also compiles under intellij. However, all the xml and manifest files are showing:
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android URI not registered in Settings | IDE Settings | Resources.

I tried ignore and manually create this but it didn't work out.

Anyone ran into similar issue? I didn't have problem w/ android SDK 2.x but this is a honeycomb 3.0 project, so just wondering if that matters.

thanks

Comment: It seems like you should use src folder to view files: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/android-studio-uri-is-not-registered

Comment: possible duplicate of [If I change an external library: AndroidManifest, cannot parse file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448866/if-i-change-an-external-library-androidmanifest-cannot-parse-file)

Answer (score 3):

I accidently opened the layout xml file which is in `out` folder (has output files for compile), not in `res` folder. Check that you opened the layout xml file in **resource folder**. The file names are identical.

Answer (score 1):

For me the problem was having a **duplicate** of my main **module** in the project structure. I removed the duplicate using the "-" button in the same dialog, and the problem got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your project is configured like android facet otherwise it will not work.
=> Project Structure : Project settings : Facets : add (+ button) android facet

This way fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

> If IntelliJ IDEA cannot find the specified DTD or schema, they are
>   marked as errors. In this case special intention actions are suggested
>   to:
>
> Resolve the reference, if it is represented as a URL. Map a URI to a
>   local file. Permanently ignore it. An ignored URI will not be
>   highlighted as an error any more, until removed from the ignore list.
>   Add Xsi schema location for external resources. A special attribute is
>   added to point namespace location. Configure schema for your XML file.
>   The schema for your XML file can be configured based on detecting
>   schemas located locally in project sources or libraries.

From here--> http://goo.gl/heQCv