# Why is Android Studio reporting "URI is not registered"?

Tags: android, android-studio

So I've given Android Studio a try, because I really like Resharper and noticed that the IDE had some of their functionality built into it. Having now created a default new project, I added a new layout file and wanted to change the existing default 'hello world' example layout, and I got an "URI is not registered" error on the following lines:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
```

I've done nothing else to the default generated project yet. I've come across another question that seems to be related ([Intellij Android project schema URI not registered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147051/intellij-android-project-schema-uri-not-registered)), but just ignoring something feels odd to me. I actually tried it, but that causes `RelativeLayout` (and probably all other Android related stuff) to be not recognised any more (error message: "Cannot find the declaration of element 'RelativeLayout'").

Any ideas on how to solve this problem?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Closing and reopening Android Studio solved this issue for me :)

Comment: Invalidate and restart cache then it works

Answer (score 169, accepted):

You are having this issue because you are at the wrong destination! The correct directory for the Layout resource file has to be under "res-layout" not "res-all-layout"

Comment: Ah yes, you are absolutely right. The mistake I made was that I opened the file from <project root>\<project name>\build\res\all\debug\layout (it is open by default I think, and being used to working from top to bottom I guess that explains the confusion).
Instead, one should indeed look at <project root>\<project name>\src\main\res\layout.

Comment: i had same issue for manifest file what to do

Comment: I hit rhe same problem but my paths were correct.  It was finally fixed by invalidate/restart.  Just invalidating the cache didn't work.  AUGH! :)

Comment: for me invalidate/restart worked. thanks @stevensmith

Comment: Sorry but I don't think this answer is entirely correct. It's absolutely valid to place resources under different folders ***if you have*** different build variants. For me, switching the build variant back and forth once fixed this problem

Comment: The issue arises with product flavors too. If you place a layout file under <myFlavour>\res\layout -which is valid- the error pops up in my case. And that prevents the IDE from previewing the file.

Answer (score 55):

For me this was because I was using a debug and release build variant. I added the new folders src/debug/res/layout/some_layout.xml file manually, and it didn't recognize the URI. I switched the build variant to release, and then back to debug. This caused Android Studio to reload something, and the error went away.

EDIT:
Also check that you have the correct filename. I had this issue again by adding a debug AndroidManifest.xml, but mistakenly named it AndroidManifest.xml.xml.

Comment: This worked for me. For those looking for how to switch the build variant, it's at the leftmost panel of AS, written sideways. Click it, then under it "debug" is actually a dropdown.

Comment: For me, the same was true. If you are looking at different flavor-layout of the app's customized, then what is loaded by Android studio, you would get an error.

Comment: This works like a charm!! thanks

Comment: You saved my day !!

Answer (score 39):

I use Intellij IDEA but I think it will also work in Android Studio, can you see the "Event Log" at IDE right bottom corner, did it have some message like that "**Android framework is detected in the project Configure**", that means you should have a framework configuration. If so, just follow the message link.
In the same way, you can go to "**File > Project Structure > Modules**" , and then add a Android Facet.

[image]

by the way, if I want use a customized namespace like you do, I'll write the resource identifier as my package name as I define the AndroidManifest.xml package attribute of the manifest element, below is my code.

```
<manifest package="com.my.name.android">
    ...
</manifest>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.name.android">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: @Michael Alan Huff, thank you so much for you teach me.

Comment: no problem :) happy stacking.

Answer (score 20):

This problem appeared suddenly for me, without any reason. I just closed all the tabs in Android Studio and re-opened the xml file which had problems. Problem solved! :)

Comment: saved my life... :)

Comment: thats only helps until the next time I am tring to run the app

Comment: Invalidate and restart cache then it works

Comment: It worked somehow. I just kept opened the tab for xml alone which had the problems, closed AS, opened again. It worked.

Comment: This solution, with invalidate and restart cache, still works.

Answer (score 8):

In Android Studio 3.1.2 this error occurs due to Wrong validation of the cache memory.,

> Go to Project folder and **delete** all the contents in **.idea folder**

This will delete the cache memory and reloading the project will create new cache memory folder and makes it good to go.,

Answer (score 7):

My problem was that my folders were structured as:

`MyProject/
          res/
              layout/
                     main.xml
                     layout-land/
                                 main.xml`

(My `Slayout-land` folder was in my `layout` folder)

I changed the structure to this and it worked for me:

`MyProject/
          res/
              layout/
                     main.xml
              layout-land/
                     main.xml`

I hope that this helps!

Answer (score 7):

Select appropriate flavour in Build Variants.

If you are viewing a particular file under Flavour1, select that flavor in BuildVariants window.

If your IDE is Android Studio (3.2.1 as of this writing), you should find Build Variants window on the lower left, aligned vertically.

Answer (score 6):

Its a plugins problems.

1. Restart Your android studio.
2. It will show a pop window for enable plugins
3. click on enable  plugins and then click on Okay.

then it will automatic restart your studio and works will fine.

hope it will works.

Answer (score 5):

Don't know the reason behind this error but I found out this somewhere and it solved my problem.

- Go to "File > Project Structure > Modules"
- Click "add **(+)**"
- Click "android" and "apply" and then "ok"

Answer (score 4):

it turns out I was editing the DEBUG version of the xml, to fix it, simply close the tab that has the error and re-open it

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error. I solved it by importing the project again to the android studio.

Answer (score 2):

- Go to "Preferences > Languages&Frameworks > Schemas and DTDS"
- Click "add(+)"
- Click "apply" and then "ok"

hope it will works.

Comment: just add your url.

Answer (score 2):

For me Plugin `Android Support` get Disabled somehow. Enabling Plugins again worked for me.

```
Settings > Plugins > Android Support
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem now - I created a new folder under the layout folder which would contain all the xml relate to my "home" page of my app and then another folder that would relate to my "settings" page as I wanted to organise my xml.

However, android only recognises the layout folder for xmls, not the layout/home or layout/settings folder so that is why it was giving me the error.

Thanks to Mazen Kasser answer, he assisted me in figuring this out.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error is correlated to other errors in your manifest. Check if there are some missing dependencies and if all the tags are closed. In my case I had deleted a folder in /res folder, I restored it and that error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the offending xml files were missing the header line...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Adding that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Started getting this again, What actually works now is to add some rubbish inside build.gradle. Then try and sync.
When it fails remove the rubbish and re-sync.
After indexing, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, which was the solution for me:
I got the error in the line

```
<resources xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:ns2="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">
```

in the values.xml file that was automatically generated during the build process.

It was solved by adding the `android` prefix in the styles.xml file.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

had to be changed to

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, i clone a project from gitlab, there is table of contents:

> TradeClient/TradeClient/app/...

then i encounter this problem, i solve the problem by below method:

- remove the middle path "TradeClient", as TradeClient/app/...
- then File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart...

Answer (score 0):

The new build system in Android Studio creates a `build` folder. The code inspection barfs on this folder as well as the `gradle` folder. These folders should proably be ignored when running code inspection.

I have raised an issue with the Android Studio team at:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=56415

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this recently trying to migrating an existing app to material design. All I had to do to fix it was change the project's Compile SDK Version. File | Project Settings. Select app and pick a Compile SDK version for Lollipop or higher.

Answer (score 0):

Any solution mentioned here helped me. I'll post my problem just in case is helpful to anyone. 
In my case the error was happening using **data binding**. It seems that using data binding xmls intermediates  are created. If there is an error trying to open the error will show the intermediate xml with this "**URI not registered**" instead of opening the right xml with the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and for me it was due to creating and manipulating resource files outside Android Studio. I followed the instructions on creating new resource files and folders through Android Studio and solved the problem. You need to create a new Resource File Not directory. It will let you specify or create a directory for you if you need it. If you are creating directories for layouts for different versions, enter the info at the top including the name of the resource file you want to copy to the new folder and select Version and enter the Android version. It will create the appropriate directory with a copy of your resource in it.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed it for me that I haven't seen mentioned so far - if you have multiple 'flavors', make sure the currently selected 'build variant' matches the flavor for the layout file you're trying to view.

Answer (score 0):

Anyone getting this error right after project import might be hitting an unsuccessful initial gradle import/sync. Usually it is encountered with serious errors (blinking exclamation mark in the lower right corner). For me this was the very strange cause (project folder was symlinked): https://stackoverflow.com/a/52952148/44166

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem in opening android React Native Project in Android Studio.

The root cause is I opened the root folder of React Native Project instead of **android folder** of the React Native Project.

Reopen the project under android folder of React Native Project solved my problem.

Answer (score -3):

Try to Install the android tracker plugin. you will find it on the studio.

Restart the studio