# How to resolve Android studio configuration issue "URI is not registered" for xmlns:android and xmlns:tools?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am facing following issue :

How to resolve Android studio configuration issue "URI is not registered" for xmlns:android and xmlns:tools in layout file ?

I have tried following solutions and did R&D but this doesn't work.

1. Check the layout file location, it should not come from build folder
2. Deleting workspace.xml file as well and clean and restart

Both above solutions did not work for me. Please let me know if any one has came accross anything like this or have some idea.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered

Comment: debug AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi I have already tried their solution earlier, it did not work. My layout file I have cross check is at correct location.

Comment: Did you rebuild project?

Comment: @adnbsr I tried cleaning and rebuilding but it did not worked.