# URI is not registered error

Tags: android, facebook, android-manifest

I imported facebook sdk successfully. When I tried to run the app, I got this error in my manifest file. I searched for this error's solution but could not find any satisfying solution. So, any help in this regard would be appreciated.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.sam.freebies" >



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <provider
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
            android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider947785421969944"
            android:exported="true" />

        <activity android:name="com.sam.freebies.MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.sam.freebies.SecondActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered

Comment: Not helpful. I checked that post. There is no issue in my layouts.

Comment: https://xkcd.com/979/