# Android Studio - URI not registered

Tags: android

I have been working on an Android application recently, and I came across an error in my `values.xml` file, in the opening tag.

**My code:**

`<resources xmlns:ns1="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">`

**Error:**
`URI is not registered (Settings | Project Settings | Schemas and DTDs)`

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here

[Why is Android Studio reporting "URI is not registered"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered][1])

> You are having this issue because you are at the wrong destination!

Comment: yeah but problem is in there