# Error in android manifest Uri not registered

Tags: android, android-manifest

Using This Sample Project To Learn More about Android https://github.com/antoniolg/MaterializeYourApp/  And To See how Is navigation Drawer work .
The Code is Giving me error in the manifest . this the manifest.Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
--- here is the error 
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
--- end here 
package="com.antonioleiva.materializeyourapp" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" ></uses-permission>

    <application >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivity"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

It Rise Error (Uri not registered)

Comment: see this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered

Comment: Its Under layout directory there is no sub directory

Comment: I found That The IC_luncher.png is missing So that was rising the error