# XML file lines In android studio are giving an error It says URI not registered

Tags: android, uri

I am receiving an error in the XML lines saying URI not registered. I've tried everything from restarting to invalidating caches. The program doesn't run because of this error. The lines are:

```
Xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered

Comment: `Xmlns:android` in this x should be small.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace `Xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` with `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`.

The 'X' should not be capital. Replace 'X' with 'x'.

Unless you made the typo here and not in your code...