# I get the "URI is not registered" message in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio

I'm a total beginner at programming. I started a new project in **Android Studio**, in Java. In the **activity_main**, I get the `"URI is not registered"` message, and I don't know how to solve it.

I'm aware to the fact that this issue has appeared in previous questions, but I've tried some of the suggested solutions there and they didn't work for me: I tried to invalidate and restart, I deleted all the contents in the idea folder, and my project is ordered: MyProject/src/res/layout/activity_main, which (I think) is the correct order.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I deepened a little more in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered), but the solutions didn't help me: I didn't understand some of them (remind you, I'm a beginner), and the ones I did understand didn't work. Perhaps they simply don't work for the newer versions of **Android Studio**?

Anyway, here's a screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried searching for the answer on this site, or post the full error log. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16883427/why-is-android-studio-reporting-uri-is-not-registered) might be related to your problem

Comment: @Igor I've seen this question and I tried a few solutions from there, but they didn't work. I understand that perhaps I didn't search that much deeply, so I'll keep looking there tomorrow; but in the meantime, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Could you edit your question with additional information i.e. add the contents of your layout that's causing the issue

Comment: Where is your activity_main package.. If you can post a screenshot of the studio would be helpful

Comment: @Igor I edited the post

Comment: Can you run your application in Android Studio? In order to fix the error display you could: 1) [ignore the schema](http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-languages-schemas-and-dtds.html) in Android Studio. 2) you could re-import your project, but before you import it again, delete `.idea` folder and `*.iml` file, so you have fresh import without any previous settings for your project in Android Studio.

Comment: Okay, Ignoring the schema worked. But does it mean the error is really solved, or is it just ignored?